# About saving DOM elements in object properties

Tags: javascript, object, dom

I want to make an UI object that saves references to DOM objects and also some UI strings, so I can use it all over my code and can handle name changes easily. Kind of like this:

```
var UI = {
    DOMelem0: document.getElementById('imUnique'),
    DOMelem1: document.getElementById('imSpecial')
};
```

However, I think that everytime I would access DOMelem0 (by calling `UI.DOMelem0`), for instance, I'd be calling the `getElementById()` function, is that what happens?

Or is it no different than storing the elem in a scoped variable? (Like so: `var elem = document.getElementById('cow');`)

I'm worried about any performance issues this might cause if I were to have lots of UI elements, although I guess they'd be minimal. Either way, I wouldn't want to be calling the DOM method all the time.
Thanks.

Comment: "no different than storing the elem in a scoped variable"

Comment: It's good to hear you're worried about performance. It's also totally irrelevant. Even if `getElementById` were to be called each time you referred to a property (it won't be), I guarantee you there would no visible effect on the performance of your app whatsoever. Although lots of questions on SO deal with performance, I'm afraid in most cases the concern is completely misplaced. Get your code well-structured and working, then optimize later.

Comment: So I could just declare the static object and just use it as it is, immediately? ```UI.DOMelem0```, or would I need to assign it to a variable with the ```new``` keyword? Do you mean the functions would be called when the browser 'compiles' the code? Sorry, I'm new to JavaScript and programming in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling UI.DOMelem0; will not call document.getElementById('imUnique').

document.getElementById('imUnique') is only called when you first create the UI object.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. Static objects are 'created' when the script is run, right? Because it needs to assign whatever you assigned to the properties immediately? It's just as if you declared a string in an object property. Sorry, I wasn't getting it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by static in this context. There is nothing static here. The instance of the object is created when the statements that define it are run by the javascript interpreter.

Comment: UI is not a class and its members are not static. UI is an instance of an object. The members of that instance are assigned their values when the object is created.

Comment: Consider accepting this answer if you believe it answered your question.